# Java: Runnable HashMap with args

Tags: java, hashmap, runnable, args

I need to make a runnable HashMap with some args in it.

*(I'm coding a game, and I want: "When a player enter a specific command it's run a specific void with args, cached in my HashMap.")*

The code will be *(maybe)* more explicit than me:

**1=>** Make a map of command list, each key should run:

-"myVoidWithArgs(arg1, arg2)"

-"myOtherVoidWithArgs(arg1, arg2)"

-etc. *(arg1 & arg2 should be strings)*

```
HashMap<String, Runnable> cmdList = new HashMap<>();
cmdList.put("teleport", () -> myVoidWithArgs(arg1, arg2));
cmdList.put("kill", () -> myOtherVoidWithArgs(arg1, arg2));
```

**2=>** And later, in an another void, get the command something like this:

```
cmdList.get("teleport").run("Player", "coords");
cmdList.get("kill").run("Player", "Message");
```

How can I do that ? Is there another way to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't tried nothing because my code above don't work with args.
I need this kind of code, who works, but with args..

Comment: Why is it not working ? Any error message to show us ?

Comment: Please read the [help], particularly [ask]. Please do not make code requests on this side. It is intended for questions and answers, and code requests are not questions. Research the subject, design your own solution, and post a question when your own solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Since the runnables need two arguments, the `Runnable` interface is not what you need for the values in the map. Use `BiConsumer<String, String>` instead; then you can do this:

```
Map<String, BiConsumer<String, String>> cmdList = new HashMap<>();

cmdList.put("teleport", (arg1, arg2) -> myVoidWithArgs(arg1, arg2));
cmdList.put("kill", (arg1, arg2) -> myOtherVoidWithArgs(arg1, arg2));
```

And you can call them like this:

```
cmdList.get("teleport").accept("Player", "coords");
cmdList.get("kill").accept("Player", "Message");
```

You can also use method references instead of lambdas to fill your map:

```
cmdList.put("teleport", SomeClass::myVoidWithArgs);
cmdList.put("kill", SomeClass::myOtherVoidWithArgs);
```

(assuming the methods are `static` methods of `SomeClass`; if not, replace `SomeClass` by a reference to the object that contains the methods).

Comment: @Jasper he need to put the value as a Runnable Object rather then simple BiConsumer. The Runnable is simple interface which take no argument and return nothing. So the value should be Runnable

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra From his post, I don't read it as that it's a hard requirement that the value needs to be a `Runnable`. If the methods need two arguments, then there's no way to fit them to the `Runnable` interface. `BiConsumer` is a lot like `Runnable`, except that it represents a function that takes two arguments (instead of no arguments) and returns nothing.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Work great! Thank you so much.

Comment: @acquiesce you point.

Comment: question is how he can call for start the executing of thread ?
**new Thread (cmdList.get("teleport").accept("Player", "coords")).start** ?

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra the original question had nothing about threads. But ofcourse you could wrap that call in a `Runnable` if you would really need to do that; or use a lambda which conforms to `Runnable`: `new Tread(() -> cmdList.get("teleport").accept("Player", "coords")).start();`